# Booking.com Failed to connect to distribution-xml.booking.com port 443

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I am using booking.com API for get all cityes and Hotels. When I send request to the fetch json data it's shwoing me Error like `Failed to connect to distribution-xml.booking.com port 443` . 
I am send request by CURL.

But when I send request to my local machine it's working well.

I don't know whether this issue is from server side? or some other issues is there.

Comment: Can you `telnet distibution-xml.booking.com 443` from the same system?

Comment: I can't from my system.

Comment: @Bluebaron: you have forgotten the r: distibution => distribution